# help with exponential integral and square root

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, improper-integrals

can somebody help me integrating this:

[image]

where m, p and q are positive constants. 
I tired change of variables and searched for the solution but could not find it.

Thanks

Note: this is the result of mathematica (zeta==a and rho==p):
[image]

but the Gamma(-0.25-0.5m) is illogical cuz this is infinity (gamma of a negative number) !!

Comment: what (and how) have you tried to solve it? Also, what is the context this comes from, because it looks like it has to do something with probability distributions.

Comment: Mathematica is able to evaluate this, but the result is extremely ugly (with multiple Hypergeometric and Gamma functions). I suggest you approximate this integral numerically.

Comment: The numerator is *almost* the gamma function (aside from that $q$), as a quick observation...

Comment: Are "m", "p" and "q" just positive constants ? Is any one an integer ?  As Ragnar wrote, for the most general case, the result is a MONSTER !

Comment: As Rangar said, it has to find the continous probability distribution. It seems very close to the gamma function, which I intended to achieve in the prior of this integration. The constants  are just real positive, may or may not be integers. Can you please add the answer of mathematica so that I can see it?

Comment: Mathematica yields $p^{-m} \Gamma(m) U(m,3/2,q/p)$, where $U$ is the [Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{m-1}e^{-qx}}{(\sqrt{1+px})^{m-0.5}}dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty x^{m-1}(1+px)^\frac{1-2m}{4}e^{-qx}~dx$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right)^{m-1}(1+x)^\frac{1-2m}{4}~e^{-\frac{qx}{p}}~d\left(\dfrac{x}{p}\right)$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{m-1}(1+x)^\frac{1-2m}{4}~e^{-\frac{qx}{p}}}{p^m}dx$$

$$=\dfrac{\Gamma(m)U\left(m,\dfrac{2m+5}{4},\dfrac{q}{p}\right)}{p^m}$$